# Can I deploy Qt as a "system library" on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, deployment, desktop-application

I am new to Qt, I installed Qt 5.6 and Microsoft compiler (I have Visual studio 2015 community). 
It works.

I am focused on QML desktop applications on Windows 7/8/10.

I can't find informations about how to deploy Qt dlls once: if I make many applications that I deploy inside corporate LAN, I would like to install all the Qt dll required in one central location, so then I will speed up the edit/compile/test/deploy cycle.

I want to install every app in its respective folder, but the Qt "runtime" and dll only ONCE, not in EVERY app's folder.

That would be a huge time waste and space (and money).

How can I do? Is this possible?

thanks

Comment: Pick a folder to store the DLLs, a subdir of c:\program files is boilerplate.  Then use Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables to add the subdir to the PATH variable.  Log out and log back in to ensure the change is effective.

Comment: is this 100% tested and working?

Comment: 44 minutes is not nearly enough for you to discover the consequences of DLL Hell and crappy installers that destroy the PATH environment variable.  You learn not to ask for features like this in the School of Hard Knocks.  Attendance required, warranty not provided.

Comment: ok so your answer is not valid, cause you are not able to tell if it is correct. Nice try mate

Answer (score 0):

Use [cqtdeployer](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/releases) with deploySystem option.

This utility can deploy system libraries.

#### Warning, deploying system libraries may cause some qt modules to work incorrectly.

1. install catdeployer from [online installer](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/releases)
2. open cmd
3. and call cqtdeployer with options:

```
cqtdeployer myApp.exe -qmlDir path/to/my/QML/folder -qmake path/to/my/qmake.exe -deploySystem
```

#### Where:

- myApp.exe -you deployment application (release version)
- -qmlDir path/to/my/QML/folder - this is path to your project qml folder
- -qmake path/to/my/qmake.exe - the path to qmake that you were going with.
- -deploySystem - option to capture system libraries.

If you wish, you can add the **qif** option to the end, this will force cqtdeployer to create an installer for your program.

```
cqtdeployer myApp.exe -qmlDir path/to/my/QML/folder -qmake path/to/my/qmake.exe -deploySystem qif
```